# How to use R for multiple select questions?

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to analyze multiple select/multiple responses (i.e., 'select all that apply') questions in a survey I recently conducted.

SPSS has nice capabilities for analyzing online survey data and these types of questions so I am guessing that R has that and more. Dealing with these survey answers is a bit tricky in Excel. For example, show me a histogram/distribution everyone who likes strawberry and chocolate ice cream by age.

How do I structure the data set and what would be the commands to perform some basic tabulations of frequency, pareto, and logical AND OR functions?

Comment: For anybody running into this now: there's now a dedicated package for this, MCRV: https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2014-1/koziol-bilder.pdf (comment by @matherion)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've not found anything that is quite as convenient as the multiple response sets in SPSS. However, you can create groups relatively easily based on common column names, and then use any of the `apply()` function or friends to iterate through each group. Here's one approach using `adply()` from the `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
set.seed(1)
#Fake data with three "like" questions. 0 = non selected, 1 = selected
dat <- data.frame(resp = 1:10,
                  like1 = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE),
                  like2 = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE),
                  like3 = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)
                  )

adply(dat[grepl("like", colnames(dat))], 2, function(x)
  data.frame(Count = as.data.frame(table(x))[2,2], 
        Perc = as.data.frame(prop.table(table(x)))[2,2]))
#-----
     X1 Count Perc
1 like1     6  0.6
2 like2     5  0.5
3 like3     3  0.3
```

Comment: at least in terms of output, this seems to just be like `colSums(dat[-1])`, and `Perc` just `Count/nrows(dat)`. Is there something more "fancy" going on that I am missing here? -- Genuinely interested because I do also have to deal with such types of questions, in which case, I'm usually less interested in dividing by the number of respondents, but by the number of responses (with this answer, 14, (`sum(dat[-1])`)).

Comment: @mrdwab - for a straight tabulation, you're probably right. `table()` will easily let you compute cross tabs as well though using the same framework and I can't easily wrap my head around how one would *easily adopt `colSums()` to handle that case, i.e. the set of questions above by gender.

Comment: Nice. I installed plyr with the Package Manager in OSX. I like that this solution will grab all "Q4" prefixed answers. In the responses, I have "1" for unchecked and "2" for checked. Somehow this solution automatically counted 2s as checked despite you using 0/1. How does it know?

Comment: @JHo - look at the output from `as.data.frame(table(x))` to see what is returned. the `[2,2]` bit just grabs the second row, second column...since you have "1" and "2", the 2 will be in the second row...let me know if that doesn't make sense

Answer (score 4):

I recently wrote a quick function to deal with these. You can easily modify it to add proportion of total responses too.

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(resp = 1:10,
                  like1 = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE),
                  like2 = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE),
                  like3 = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE))
```

The function:

```
multi.freq.table = function(data, sep="", dropzero=FALSE, clean=TRUE) {
  # Takes boolean multiple-response data and tabulates it according
  #   to the possible combinations of each variable.
  #
  # See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11348391/1270695

  counts = data.frame(table(data))
  N = ncol(counts)
  counts$Combn = apply(counts[-N] == 1, 1, 
                       function(x) paste(names(counts[-N])[x],
                                         collapse=sep))
  if (isTRUE(dropzero)) {
    counts = counts[counts$Freq != 0, ]
  } else if (!isTRUE(dropzero)) {
    counts = counts
  }
  if (isTRUE(clean)) {
    counts = data.frame(Combn = counts$Combn, Freq = counts$Freq)
  } 
  counts
}
```

Apply the function:

```
multi.freq.table(dat[-1], sep="-")
#               Combn Freq
# 1                      1
# 2             like1    2
# 3             like2    2
# 4       like1-like2    2
# 5             like3    1
# 6       like1-like3    1
# 7       like2-like3    0
# 8 like1-like2-like3    1
```

Hope this helps! Otherwise, show some examples of desired output or describe some features, and I'll see what can be added.

## Update

After looking at the output of SPSS for this online, it seems like the following should do it for you. This is easy enough to wrap into a function if you need to use it a lot.

```
data.frame(Freq = colSums(dat[-1]),
           Pct.of.Resp = (colSums(dat[-1])/sum(dat[-1]))*100,
           Pct.of.Cases = (colSums(dat[-1])/nrow(dat[-1]))*100)
#       Freq Pct.of.Resp Pct.of.Cases
# like1    6    42.85714           60
# like2    5    35.71429           50
# like3    3    21.42857           30
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this. This solution works. I had to take a couple extra steps which were a good learning exercise. Subsetting the dataset for Q4 (i.e., dat1 <- dat[c(4:15)]). And converting my nocheck(1)/check(2) notation to 0/1. It was a good learning exercise to try your solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
multfreqtable(data_set, "Banner")
multfreqtable = function(data, question.prefix) {
  z = length(question.prefix)
  temp = vector("list", z)

  for (i in 1:z) {
    a = grep(question.prefix[i], names(data))
    b = sum(data[, a] != 0)
    d = colSums(data[, a] != 0)
    e = sum(rowSums(data[,a]) !=0)
    f = as.numeric(c(d, b))
    temp[[i]] = data.frame(question = c(sub(question.prefix[i], 
                                            "", names(d)), "Total"),
                           freq = f,
                           percent_response = (f/b)*100,
                           percent_cases = (f/e)*100 )
    names(temp)[i] = question.prefix[i]
  }
  temp
}
```

does a very good job of giving you numbers, percentages at the number of cases level and percentage at the number of responses level. Perfect for analyzing Multi-Response Questions